Explanation of the proof of Corollary 10.3.5 of Kadison-Ringrose.
I am stuck at the proof of the following Corollary 10.3.6 in the book Kadison-Ringrose II. In the proof the authors used Kaplansky density theorem in the second line as follows:

With $\pi = \pi_\rho \oplus \pi_\tau$, it follows from Theorem 10.3.5 that
$$
\pi(\mathfrak{A})^{-}= \pi_\rho(\mathfrak{A})^{-} \oplus \pi_\tau(\mathfrak{A})^{-}.
$$
(note that here '$^-$' is the wot closure of an algebra). From this, together with Kaplansky density theorem, there is a net $\{T_a\}$ in the unit ball of $\pi(\mathfrak{A})$ that converges ultraweakly to the element $I \oplus (-I)$ of $\pi_\rho(\mathfrak{A})^- \oplus \pi_\tau(\mathfrak{A})^-$.

But by Kaplansky density theorem (Theorem 5.3.5 of vol 1) $T_a$ should converges in wot. Why it converges in ultraweak topology? Another question is that for an self-adjoint algebra of operators $\mathfrak{A}$, is it true that $\mathfrak{A}^-=\mathfrak{A}^{-\text{ultrawk}}$?

On the norm unit ball, WOT and the ultraweak topology coincide, so $T_a$ converging in WOT and ultraweakly mean the same thing. (This fact is likely in the book somewhere, but if not, it is a relatively easy exercise that can be proved either using a $3\epsilon$-argument, or using the fact that a continuous bijection between compact Hausdorff spaces is necessarily a homeomorphism.)
For the second question, yes, and it follows from Kaplansky density theorem. Since WOT is coarser than the ultraweak topology, we have $\mathfrak{A}^- \supset \mathfrak{A}^{-\text{ultrawk}}$. For the converse, it suffices to show that, for any $T \in \mathfrak{A}^-$ in the norm unit ball, $T$ is contained in $\mathfrak{A}^{-\text{ultrawk}}$. By Kaplansky density theorem, there is a net $\{T_a\}$ in the norm unit ball of $\mathfrak{A}$ converging to $T$ in WOT. Again, on the norm unit ball, WOT and the ultraweak topology coincide, so $T_a \to T$ ultraweakly as well, which implies $T \in \mathfrak{A}^{-\text{ultrawk}}$, as required.
